# Personal links/database manager that allows to add preview images for items

Tags: windows, database, file-management, bookmark

I want to store links to files and web pages, and each item should at least have some tags, title, and preview image —
similar to how modern online catalogues present their items for the user! Of course, there must be some built-in search engine to find items quickly (using tags/title). Is there any app that is able to do this?
By the way, such an app must have some lazy-loading mechanism or pagination to avoid loading all the images if I have many items.
I tried many personal database managers and bookmarks organizers, but they all don't satisfy those basic requirements...

Comment: Store on your local PC (if so, which o/s? On on the web somewhere? Free, or do you have budget?

Comment: Not on web, of course - this is a **personal** database manager. Having a portable version -- I don't want to see heavyweight installers requiring admin rights and integrating to my OS/browsers. Not written in Java/.Net. Regarding its price - it doesn't matter right now. I want to see anything appropriate, and I will decide if I want to use it.

Comment: @lyricallywicked Can you explain a bit more of what you need? That first sentence is not clear. Do you mean just a web browser bookmark collection?

Comment: @BasilBourque: browser bookmark collection might be enough (if I will be able to open the bookmark with the default OS associated app, eg. open PDFs with a PDF viewer), but the problem it **does not allow to add a preview image for a bookmark**!

Comment: What do you mean by "a preview image for a bookmark"? An image of the rendered web page?

Comment: @BasilBourque: "An image of the rendered web page?" - no, this is absolutely useless for me. I want to select **any image (local file)** as a preview!

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest taking a look at [rednotebook](http://rednotebook.sourceforge.net/) I think that the only thing missing is that you would have to generate the previews yourself.

- Price: Free
- Storage format: Plain text, (markdown), archive to .zip
- Platform: Windows, OS-X, Linux
- Links & email addresses, Yes
- Tags, use #tags
- Search, Yes!
- Spell Check - Yes.
- Previews - Not automatically, but you can add images if you wish.

Comment: I tried this app before I asked this question. No, it's definitely not what I want. As far as I understand, it allows to insert an image **inside** of an item, but not to **preview** an item in a list! "RedNotebook is a modern journal"? BTW, I could not even start to use this app - I do not understand its interface, I do not understand how it works. I don't need no journals, no notebooks, no tree viewers! A simple, but user-friendly catalogue! As in all modern online shops! Actually, I'm very shocked and annoyed by the fact that I cannot find anything! Such a simple, obvious requirements...

Comment: You __do__ realize that that those _simple_, online, catalogs, such as "all online shops" have consist of a database & web server with a full time administrative team, supported by 1000s of hours of programming, DB & web customization then with photographers & data entry staff with each entry taking between 5 & 50 minutes to add by experienced data entry staff. Try adding a decent listing to eBay yourself. BTW RedNotebook has one of the simplest UIs I know.

Comment: "You do realize that that those simple, online, catalogs, such as "all online shops" have consist of a database & web server..." - I do rrealize that, but that is meant to serve the highload online activity with **a lot** of functionality and logic, and I am asking for a simple personal app! Such app will require not more than SQLite as a database. "each entry taking between 5 & 50 minutes to add by experienced data entry staff" - I don't know what you mean, but there's **a lot** of sites which allow **the user** to add their favorite items in a moment.

Comment: Regarding RedNotebook - can you post a screenshot containing just a few images, where each image is a link to file/webpage and can be found by tag search? Maybe I'm missing something, but I think this app is not supposed to do this.

Comment: Your question did not specify that the links had to be picture links, just that there had to be links & pictures.

Comment: I meant "picture link" when I said "preview image"

Answer (score -1):

You can try [Flamory](https://flamory.com). It does pretty much the thing that you described. It saves a snapshot of the page. You can later find it by looking through the list of thumbnails or by any words from that page.

Each page snapshot will show you a screenshot of the place you saved, and you can also switch to live page preview, or open saved page copy.

These snapshots work as bookmarks too, so when you double click them, Flamory will take you to the exact place on the page that you bookmarked (including scroll position).

Comment: No, it's definitely not what I am asking about. First of all, this software has no portable version and requires .NET framework 4.5 installation to my OS. No, I won't even try to use it. I forgot to mention that I won't use any app that's written in Java or .Net. Moreover, this app is supposed to search inside visited web pages, it cannot assign tags to items, it cannot allow me to select, say, a jpg image and use it as a thumbnail...